# ansible -i hosts all -u root -m ping -vvvv fail

Tags: ssh, ansible, ping

My hosts:

```
➜  ansible cat hosts
[Production]
60.205.94.138
```

My `ansible.cfg`:

```
➜  ansible cat ansible.cfg
[Production]
60.205.94.138 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/Users/yuanyuan/.ssh/yyb
```

My command, and its results:

[image]

The ssh command:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/yyb.pub root@60.205.94.138
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ansible.cfg` incorrectly. The content you have in there should be in your hosts file.

Try `hosts`:

```
[Production]
60.205.94.138 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/Users/yuanyuan/.ssh/yyb
```

and:

```
$ ansible all -i hosts -u root -m ping
```